# How to open the navigation pane in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, function, navigation

I clicked something and now the navigation pane is gone. How do I get it back so I can see everything? I would post a picture but its not letting me

Comment: Window -> Show View -> Navigator

Answer (score 14):

You go to Window -> Show View -> package explorer
if it's not listed, click on "Other" and type it in.

Answer (score 6):

GO to **Window** option of elicpse ,
click on  **ShowView** Go to **other >> General >> Navigation** and press **OK**.

Answer (score 1):

In order to open the Nvaigator in eclipse you need to follow the following

1. Click on `Windows` option in the Toolbar
2. Click on `Show View` option
3. Select the Navigator option.

This will open up the navigator in your eclipse